# Fetch specific data form array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can echo all data form this array but how can I get fetch the first data and second data separately?
I echo this get all user_id, I want to separately save user_id in somewhere.

```
    <?php
        use App\AssignSubmission;

        $user = auth()->user();
        $AssignSubmissions = AssignSubmission::with('submissions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    foreach ($AssignSubmissions as $AssignSubmission)
    {
        echo $AssignSubmission->submissions->user_id;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are the two data ?

Comment: I can echo all data from this array but now I only want to echo the specific data I want

Comment: Try like this 
        echo $AssignSubmission->submissions[0]->user_id;.    
        echo $AssignSubmission->submissions->[1]user_id;

Comment: Use the `->limit(2)->get()` to limit your query. Then echo all items in your `foreach`

Comment: @AmolRokade `->submissions` looks like it's a relation, not a array or am I missing some advanced Laravel syntax? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->submissions` is a relation, so you can easily limit the number of items you're getting with the query builder using `->limit(2)` before the `->get()`. Then only the first 2 get loaded.

If you need all others as well, then you might instead want to use a counter inside your `foreach` that will trigger a `break;` call inside a `if` statement inside the `foreach` loop:

```
var $cnt = 0;
foreach(....) {
    $cnt++;
    if ($cnt > 2) break;
    ...
}
```

For more information, have a look at Laravel's documentation on:

- [Database queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)
- [Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)
- [Database in general](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database)

Comment: yes it is relation what if I just want the 2nd data

Comment: Use `->offset(1)->limit(1)->get()`. This is all in Laravel’s excellent documentation on Database, have a look there for more details and info.